# If the third derivative of $\frac{x^4}{(x-1)(x-2)}$ is $\frac{-12k}{(x-2)^4}$ + $\frac{6}{(x-1)^4}$ then the value of k is?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-fractions

In the answers I found on google, see [this](https://www.sarthaks.com/1699768/if-the-third-derivative-of-x-4-x-1-x-2-is-12k-x-2-4-6-x-1-4-then-the-value-of-k-is) link, they converted the given function into a certain form? What is the process of that conversion (I understand it is a partial fraction of sorts, but how to get there I do not know)? And in the subsequent steps, the factorial part made no sense to me either.

So yes, how do I proceed?

Comment: Please [don’t use links](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem) instead of [typing your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), and show your attempts. To begin with, since you "understand it is a partial fraction of sorts", apply what you were taught about partial fractions, to decompose that fraction.

Comment: Reference [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division).

Answer (score 2):

welcome to MSE; As a hint:try like below
$$\frac{x^4}{(x-1)(x-2)}=ax^2+bx+c+\frac{d}{x-1}+\frac{e}{x-2}$$ find $a,b,c,d,e$ then apply derivation.
Remark: You can use dividing $x^4$ to $(x-1)(x-2)$ to simplify the fraction. It is not so hard to find $a,b,c,d,e$ for example if you think twice you will find $a=1$ and you can multiply both sides by $(x-1)$ and put $x=1 $ to find $d$ , and multiply bot sides by $(x-2)$ then put $x=2$ to find $e$